# In Firebase, how do you update the displayName field of a user in Auth?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I currently have a function that creates a user account. I'd like to be able to add a username field too, but I can't seem to figure out how to update that. I noticed in the Google console, that there is a displayName field that is set to null. I don't know how to change it. This is what I have:

```
function create(email, password, username) {
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
        $timeout(function() {
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            console.log(errorCode.toUpperCase() + ":" + errorMessage);
        })
    });
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
            $timeout(function() {
                console.log("Success! Account Created!");
                user.displayName = username; /* this doesn't work*/
            });
        } else {}
    });
}
```

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#update_a_users_profile

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`firebase.auth.Auth` gives you a `firebase.User`. You should check out the methods you can run on `User`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User

Seems like you're looking for `updateProfile`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#update_a_users_profile

**Update:** The link changes often, see sub-comments for latest

Comment: Link to updateProfile docs has changed to https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#update-profile

Comment: Its moved again... 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#update_a_users_profile